# PostgreSQL how to check table existence?

Tags: postgresql

This is how we can check table existence in MSSQL:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'public."TABLE_NAME"', N'U') IS NOT NULL
select 1 as 'column'
else 
select 0 as 'column';
```

which stores outcome in variable 'column'

How can I do same thing in PostgreSQL ? I want to return 1 or 0 for respective outcome.

Comment: `select 1 as "column"` does not "store" the data anywhere. It merely assigns a column alias to a constant value.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes that is what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a SELECT with an EXISTS operator checking e.g. `information_schema.tables`:

```
select exists (select *
               from information_schema.tables
               where table_name = 'table_name' 
                 and table_schema = 'public') as table_exists;
```

If you can't (or won't) deal with proper boolean values, the simply cast the result to a number (but I have no idea why that should be better):

```
select exists (select *
               from information_schema.tables
               where table_name = 'table_name' 
                 and table_schema = 'public')::int as "column";
```

Note that `column` is a reserved keyword and thus you need to quote it using double quotes.

Comment: then use `as "column"` instead of `as table_exists` - why would you want to use a cludge with zero and 1 if you have a proper boolean result?

Answer (score 2):

Check for column in a table existence use view [pg_tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/view-pg-tables.html)

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT attname 
    FROM pg_attribute 
    WHERE attrelid = (SELECT oid FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'YOURTABLENAME') 
    AND attname = 'YOURCOLUMNNAME')
THEN
-- do something
END IF;
```

For my sql use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

```
SELECT 1
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
  [AND table_schema = 'db_name']
  [AND column_name LIKE 'wild']
```

Comment: Pratik wants to check for a table existence, not for a column in a known table.